# MYSQL5.7 my.ini file not reflecting

Tags: mysql, innodb

I am using MYSQL5.7, installed using msi option in Windows. I want to change the innodb_buffer_pool_size. I went through stackoverflow and find out how to change the mysql.ini file.

For MYSQL5.7, i tried to change the my.ini file in the below location as described in stackoverflow.

Option1;

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7.  I made the changes in the my-default.ini file and stopped the mysql service and started again.  Its not working

So i copied the my-default.ini to my.ini and tried again. Its not working
```

Option2:

```
    I echo the programdata, then i found another location. C:\ProgramData\MySQL and in that i found 4 ini files. I changed everything and stopped and started the MYSQL service. Its also not working. 

Please help me to understand why the ini file is not reflected and how to resolve this issue
```

Comment: Can you see what options are on the running `mysqld`?

Comment: Please advise what it mean?

Comment: See if task manager will show you the parameters that are on the `mysqld` command when it is running.  I am wondering if it is pointing to a different place for the .ini file.

Answer (score -1):

Keep my.ini file in stall mysql location, and run `net stop mysql`, `net run mysql`.
If `net run mysql` is ok, then my.ini will be ok.

Comment: Please edit your question to contain an explanation about what to change, and what else to do